# Trying to import an Aegir backup to new server

Tags: drush, aegir

I've been following the instructions http://community.aegirproject.org/content/importing-existing-aegir-backups/ on how to import a site.

I have the backup .tar.gz from another hosting provider on my server but I cant get the drush command to run?

When I check the `drush sa` for the platform it does not get listed but in the aegir admin it show up under platforms?

Should I be running the drush command in a specific directory? I have been using `/var/aegir/hostmaster-7.x-3.9/sites/aegir.domain.name`

Regards

Keith

Comment: The more up to date docs about that topic are on http://docs.aegirproject.org/en/3.x/usage/sites/importing/ Please use those :)

Comment: Thank you for the updated doc's link. But it doesn't suggest in the Importing a single site manually step 1 say which directory to run the

drush provision-save ... 
drush provision-install ...

commands.
Regards
Keith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many directory's the correct one to run appears to be    `/var/aegir/platforms`

The `drush sa` now lists the installed profiles and the `drush provision-save ...` and `drush provision-deploy ...` now run.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the drush alias for hostmaster here:
`drush @hostmaster sa`

You may need to switch to the aegir user first.